# Google Calendar API trigger when new event is created from Calendly

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api

I have a Google AppScript for adding 3rd party video conferencing to Calendar events. I am looking for a way to add video conferencing automatically when an event is created in Google Calendar via an external client like Calendly. How would I set up this trigger and identify new Calendly events?

Comment: Could you please show what research you did till now, what have you tried, and what specific issues you are facing? Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring push notifications using 'watch'?
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch